# Azure SQL Database SQL71562 error exporting to blob storage

Tags: azure-sql-database

I am attempting to export an Azure SQL Database on an elastic pool to blob storage via the portal Export selection from the target database.

This errors with:
One or more unsupported elements were found in the schema used as part of a data package.
Error SQL71562: Error validating element (and a partial listing of objects follows).

When moving from on-premises to Azure there were things that had to been done regarding database tables and stored procedures to ensure a successful bacpac creation.  It appears that is the case even with Azure SQL Databases but not finding anything that documents this (not sure why unsupported objects could be created within SQL Database).  Anyone else experience this?

Answer (score 0):

This is an error I’ve seen after migrating to Azure; usually in stored procedures. The error is seen when something has a four-part table reference. For example: `[server].[database].[schema].[table]`. These are not supported and result in a `SQL71562` error.

You may be able to identify the issue by querying your `[sys]` tables for procedures and views that specifically reference a server or database.

For stored procedures:

```
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(object_id),
       OBJECT_DEFINITION(object_id)
  FROM sys.procedures
 WHERE OBJECT_DEFINITION(object_id) LIKE '%[DB_NAME]%'
```

For views:

```
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(object_id),
       OBJECT_DEFINITION(object_id)
  FROM sys.views
 WHERE OBJECT_DEFINITION(object_id) LIKE '%[DB_NAME]%'
```

Be sure to replace `DB_NAME` with the name of one of your databases.

Comment: We don't use elastic query so multi-part naming doesn't apply for our Azure SQL Databases.  Multi-part naming in our database objects was removed before converting the databases to bacpac files.